# Delete an account from Android without affecting the apps related to it

Tags: applications, accounts

I have three accounts in my Android phone. I have apps installed in the phone via them. 
Now I want to **delete one of the account (NOT primary) but don't want to lose the apps** related to them.

Is there a way to do that?

Or if I **can move my apps from one account to another**, so that after doing this I can delete the second account?

Comment: Are these purchased apps our free ones?

Comment: some are purchased and some are free... but more importantly I can not loose the data in them ... its about data of 1.5 yrs ...

Comment: If you're worried about losing data, I'd strongly advise getting Titanium Backup and doing a full backup of your phone before you make any changes.  That way if anything happens to go wrong, you can just restore from the backup.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting a secondary account won't delete the already installed apps associated with the account, AFAIK.  However, that's a loophole that Google might plug in the future.

It's not possible to move apps from one account to another.

Comment: thanks @Logos ... so Will I be able to update those apps even after I have deleted the account related to them?

Comment: Yes, the apps should still update.